# unable to display output of spline interpolation script using octave

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, octave, interpolation

I am trying following script for spline 2d interpolation using octave in centos 7 but nothing is display only one octave workplace is generated in folder which i unable to open.please let me know what should i add in this script to get output. and also let me know how to write this script for 3d interpolation.

```
data=load('data.txt'); 

x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);

obs = data(:,3);
```

[xi,yi] = ndgrid(-2:0.1:2,-2:0.1:2);

```
m = 30;
mean_obs = mean(obs);

f = obs - mean_obs;
var = 0.01 * ones(size(f));

[fi,vari] = optiminterp2(x,y,f,var,1.5,1.5,m,xi,yi);

obsi = fi + mean_obs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove a semi-colon from the end of a line of code to see the result of the computation on that line.  All your code ends in semi-colons so you're suppressing the output.  It would help a lot if you formatted the code snippet a lot better by the way - it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: As you say i edit my question, I do that but nothing is happen n   aslo want to write 3d interpolation script using it but unable please help me out.